# select a row from a listview from an other class

Tags: java, android, listview

i want to select the next row position in a list view from an other class but i don't know how to do it. I got the list to pass the position clicked to the other class. in the onItemclick listener

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> vie, View view,
                int agr2 , long agr3){

            Intent i = new Intent(context, Test.class);
            i.putExtra("numbers", agr2);
            startActivity(i);
        }
```

In test.java, i got the value and made the value as

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    int num = extras.getInt("numbers");
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviews);
    int randomb = 1;

    int rand = num - randomb;
    if (rand == -1){
        rand = 100;
    }

    tv.setText("next row to go to :  "+ rand +"  selectedrow :  "+ num );
```

so my goal is that some how i can put the int "rand" somewhere so it goes to the next row, when lets say i press a button or a timer goes to zero.

thanks in advance.

Comment: "so my goal is that some how i can put the int "rand" somewhere so it goes to the next class". You mean a third class? I don't think this structure is well thought, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Carnal no sry that is supposed to say row

Comment: I still don't get what you mean with "so it goes to the next row".

Comment: imagine i have a timer and when the timer = 0, he then goes to the next row and shows the content in there and so on.

Comment: What is the role of test.java in you flow..

Comment: i want it to display information for a certain time and then go to the next row in the list view of the previous class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking lots of assumption, I think you want to send back the rand to the ListActivity.. so the calling graph would be like following

ListActivity (clicked list item id in intent) --> Randomizer Activity (not sure why u need it)  woudl perform some magic and would generate a random variable (you need to pass that back to List activity) --> ListActivity

for this use case you can use startActivityForResult(). please check out the following tutorial:

http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/08/android-developer-tutorial-for_31.html

EDIT1:

You can also use the setSelection() method to select a particular row..

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelection(int)

Comment: thank you but that is only the first part :( , i now need to know how i can get that value, and put it somewhere so it selects the row i need

Comment: Again assuming that you want to select a particular row in list.. you can use this method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelection(int)...

Answer (score 0):

Keep the value of rand in [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

You can access the value anywhere in the application and update as and when required.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, if you want a timer to trigger the event that "go to the next row" then all you should do is just to increase that rand number is your TimerActionListener method and visit the "next row".

Comment: i can pull that trick off, but how can i go to the next row when the timer is 0

Comment: you just have to implement an Action Listener for you timer, just like how you implement the buttonClickListener.
There is a similar thread: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050588/how-to-implement-actionlistener-inside-a-timer-program
Or you can google with key word:"Timer ActionListener Tutorial".